# ASP.NET MVC 3 product list with login partial page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable

I am a new MVC 3 user, and I am trying to develop E-Commerce website.
When I created product list by using product model, I cannot put login partial page because I am also using Customer model in logOnPartial page.

It has errors 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication2.Models.Product]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcApplication2.Models.Customer''.

I understand what does it mean. However, I don't know how to display login partial page with product list in a page? Is it possible?
I give you some my code. What shall I do? Thanks you for reading.

```
//mac.cshtml page

@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication2.Models.Product>

<div id="border_frame">
@Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
</div>
```

Currently, I am using Customer models in logOnPartial page.

```
//logOnPartial.cshtml page
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Customer

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
<text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
[ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text><br />
}
else
{
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.userName)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userName, new { style = "width:150px;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.userName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.password)

    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.password, new { style = "width:150px;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.password) 

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="login_button" value="Log in"/>
    @Html.ActionLink("Register now", "Register", "Account", null, new { @class = "register_button" });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial", <You need to pass an instance of Customer here>)
```

You are trying to render _LogOnPartial view which requires as a model an instance of `Customer`. Since you're not passing any object explicitly (there's an override on `Partial` that takes a model) the whole existing model is passed (`IEnumerable<MvcApplication2.Models.Product>`
). This is not a valid model for your partial view, hence the error.

I would suggest that you change the model for mac view from `IEnumerable<Product>` to a new view model class

```
class ProductsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can pass your customer to the partial view

```
@Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial", Model.Customer)
```

Comment: Then I cannot user _LogonPartial view in product list? how can I pass an instance of customer? Sorry, I am new MVC, then could you explain a little bit more with some practices?